Jpa with hibernate spatial and postgis not working
application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_postgis
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

dependencies:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '6.5.0.Final'

//dont know if its necessary nothing changes with or without
implementation group: 'org.locationtech.jts', name: 'jts-core', version: '1.19.0'

entity:
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "GEOM")
public class Geom {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_GEOM")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "POLYG", columnDefinition = "geometry(Polygon,4326)")
    private Polygon polyg;
}

table:
CREATE TABLE geom (
    id_geom SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    polyg GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326)
);

Error on compilation:
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: 
Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect]
as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Tried changing from org.hibernate.orm to the old org.hibernate, still got the same error
Tried removing the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialec propertie, then it compiles and run, but when I try to request it it gives the following error:
[nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Ignoring exception,
response committed already: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

[nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
[org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)]

the response JSON:
[{"id":1,"polyg":{"envelope":{"envelope":{"envelope":{"envelope":..........}}}}}}}}}

tried different JTS such as vividsolution jts, but it seens to be moved to jts-core
tried different and older versions of hibernate spatial tried even the PgPolygon
nothing seens to work
edit: already tried everything found on:

Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect]...
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031 this was my initial error
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion...


Can you provide the versions of Hibernate , Springboot, Java (or just share your pom.xml)

You should delete the spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect. You don't need to specify a spatial dialect for Hibernate 6 and later, and the standard resolution mechanisms should just work for Postgresql + Postgis.
